# How to trigger event handler when session timeout in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eventhandler

Is there a way to call event handler when session is up? below is my eventhandler for logout.

```
class AuthLogoutEventHandler
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

  public $user;

  public function __construct($user)
  {
      $this->user = $user;
  }
}
```

Already registered my Eventhandler and listener in EventServiceProvider.php

Comment: Which event do you want to listen to?

Comment: when browser is closed, or when session is timeout.